# Understanding the "Guess and Check" definition of $NP$.

Tags: definition, computer-science, computational-complexity

Aside from the normal complexity definition of $NP:= \bigcup_{k \geq 1} \ NTIME$, we have an alternative definition ("Guess and Check") of NP

> A language $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$ is in $NP$ , if there exist a
> polynomial $p: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ and a deterministic Turing
> Machine $M$, so that for every $x \in \Sigma^*$ we have:
>
> $$x \in L \iff \exists u \in \Sigma^{p(\vert x \vert)} : \langle x,u \rangle \in
> T(M)$$
>
> If $\langle x,u \rangle \in T(M)$ then $u$ is considered as a **certificate** of
> $x$.

So essentially we use the string $u$ to help us determine a solution but I am not sure if I understand this definition properly.

Comment: Have you seen the wikipedia article https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity, I am going to be a little bit informal. This is according to a nice chapter in "Graph Theory" by Bondy and Murty.

We define a decision problem as a question whose answer is either "yes" or "no". A decision problem belongs to $\mathcal{P}$ if every instance of the problem can be solve in polynomial time by some algorithm. It belongs to $\mathcal{NP}$ if, given any instance of the problem whose answer is "yes", there is a certificate validating this fact which can be checked in polynomial time; such a certificate is said to be succinct. (If the answer is "no" and there is such a certificate which can be validated in polynomial time then the problem is in $co-\mathcal{NP}$).

Now, using the formal definition that you have provided. Our turing machine $M$ accepts every word $x \in L$ if and only if there is a word $u$ of length bounded from above by $p(|x|)$ and $M$ accepts the pair $<x,u>$. The point is that $M$ accepts $x$ using $u$ in polynomially many steps, since $u$ has size at most $p(|x|)$.

For example, solving a hereditary property based problem on a simple, undirected graph $G$ (which is a property which must hold for each induced subgraph), we have to check each induced subgraph $H$ of $G$. This boils down to enumerate all subsets of the vertex set $V$ and if $|V|=n$ there are $2^n$ possible subsets. But if a solution is provided, it **could** be essentially faster to check if this solution is correct.

Furtheremore, the term "Guess and check" is often used in relationship with non-deterministic Turing machines. We guess a solution of our problem instance (which is generated in a non-deterministic way) and then verify its solution in polynomially many steps by some deterministic Turing machine.

**In other words:** $L$ is in $\mathcal{NP}$ if $x \in L$ can be verified by an algorithm encoded by $u$ whereby $u$ has length at most $p(|x|)$, and this holds for all words of $L$.

**Example:** Take an instance of the SAT problem. Is $(x_1 \land \lnot x_2) \lor (x_1 \land x_3) \lor (\lnot x_2 \land x_3)$ satisfiable? Now, perform the following steps:

1. Guess $n$-bit vector,
2. Verify the guessed vector, simply by calculating the formula of the given instance.

SAT is obviously in $\mathcal{NP}$.

Comment: Please stop suggesting trivial edits, by doing nothing more than surrounding an adjective with dollar signs, e.g. if the only edit you can come up with is to turn "6 eggs" into "$6$ eggs" - DON'T DO IT.  Suggest edits to posts that need more substantial edits, please.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I wasn't aware of that particular policy. I will pay attention to it in the future.

Comment: No problem.  Once you earn 2k rep, you aren't subject to reviews (nor do you earn 2 points per review).  Everyone, including myself, learns a lot by suggesting edits.  Thanks for your reply!